# RealmJson.Extensions - How to import entire JSOn?

Tags: json, xamarin, realm

I am using https://github.com/sushihangover/Realm.Json.Extensions to import a JSON into my realm database. However, only the top level object is created but not all nested objects in the JSON.

Below an example. Imagine three classes: A, B and C. A containing B and B containing C.

```
 public class A : RealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    [Backlink(nameof(B.A))]
    public IQueryable<B> BList { get; }
}

public class B : RealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    public A A { get; set; }
    [Backlink(nameof(C.B))]
    public IQueryable<C> CList { get; }
}

public class C : RealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    public B B { get; set; }
}
```

When I export my database to json I get the following:

```
{
  "$id": "1",
  "Id": "979e7341-0d16-4ba4-b91b-31ec81bb18ad",
  "BList": [
    {
      "$id": "2",
      "Id": "dbb35317-eae0-4978-9675-e0246805fc34",
      "CList": [
        {
          "$id": "3",
          "Id": "2da5ac92-bc73-4f80-8a27-051bbf4e5e66",
        },
        {
          "$id": "4",
          "Id": "a40f7f12-7eee-47ee-845f-4481b72c0109",
        },
        {
          "$id": "5",
          "Id": "37606fc1-74a0-4a9e-a802-587076429edc",
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

However, when I call:

```
using (var r = Realm.GetInstance()) {
   var s = r.CreateObjectFromJson<A>(json);
}
```

Only the parent object A is created without any of the children (1 B object and 3 C objects).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Realm-based forward `IList` properties hierarchies are supported as NewtonSoft.Json can handle adding objects to the read-only ILists in a forward descending tree. But Realm-based BackLinks properties require that the backlink objects pre-exist in order to be added to the read-only `IQueryable` backlist collection and NewtonSoft does not handle that scenario automatically (nor could it as far as I am aware). I'll flag the GitHub issue you created as a bug/enhancement and see what I can do.

Comment: Basically you would need to dump the backlists objects (in reverse order if there are hierarchies there) as separate json files, and then dump the main/containing backlink object(s). To reload, you then would load the backlinks first, and work your way in reverse order up the descending backlink tree